# access sql query to select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to sql and have a simple question. I have two tables, t1 and t2, both have same fields A, B, C,D

I want to create a sql that

```
select 
   * 
from t1 
where (t1.A exist in t2.A) 
AND (combination (ABC) from t1 not exist in t2)
```

I am using access 2013

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using exists logic:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.A = t1.A) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.B = t1.B AND t2.C = t1.C);
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help. I am using Access and encounter "Enter Parameter Value" message for each field in t2 using your sql.

Comment: @Solitude I think this is a table alias issue, check my updated answer for what you actual query might look like.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE 
    A in (SELECT A from t2) AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM t2
        WHERE t1.B = t2.B AND
        t1.C = t2.C AND
        t1.D = t2.D
    );
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for the help. I am using Access and encounter "Enter Parameter Value" message for each field in t2 using your sql.

Comment: Is t2 the real table name? If you are getting that error it may be because you are using a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words) as a table name